# How can convert html file to ics (iCal) file

Tags: html, converters, icalendar, rfc5545

Hello I would like to convert a `html` file ( web site ) to `ics` `(iCal)` file. 
Is it possible? If yes how can I do that? Knows anyone?

Thank you

Comment: Not sure I understand. Most HTML files have nothing in common with an iCal file, which contains a calendar event. How would this work, using what criteria?

Comment: Why does this question have 3 upvotes? It shows zero research effort.

Comment: So the answer is that is not possible?

Comment: I have a hmp100 spinetix device witch I want to preview a web site. This device accepts only .ics, .rss and svg file. Not html. So  I asked if is it possible to convert a html to ics file. I think.. I think it is not a crime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean a HTML file that contains data about a certain event, such as a meeting or a convention, what you can do is **parse the HTML** for the relevant data and create a new iCal file from that.

Study the HTML, find out how to use regular expressions to find the data that you need, then create a new iCal file and write the parsed data to it. You'll need the following steps:

1) GET the HTML to a local file

2) Parse it, producing an in-memory object with the parsed values

3) Validate that in-memory object against a number of rules (any rules that you can think of that apply in your case, such as making sure that the date and time are in a correct format and that the date is in the future, etc.)

4) Write the data to a file in iCal (RFC 2445) format.

The format definition of iCal can be found at http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt but you'll find this page easier to understand: http://reefknot.sourceforge.net/bootstrap-guide/indexs05.html

Good luck!